# How to change sprite in gridpath movement

Tags: game-maker, gml

There are 4sprite that show left,right,up,down and i made movement used gridpath movement so i want to make like this

if  playerobject go left, change spr_left

How to make it in gridpath?

Comment: Please provide example code in your question.  What form are you refering too?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check out what the last direction of the player was;

```
if (x < xprevious) {
    sprite_index = spr_right;
}
if (x > xprevious) {
    sprite_index = spr_left;
}
if (y < yprevious) {
    sprite_index = spr_up;
}
if (y > yprevious) {
    sprite_index = spr_down;
}
```